# select case and drop downbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am a beginner in ASP.Net and I am currently having problems trying to understand the mechanics of using the drop-down list.

My problem is I am trying to use a `Select Case` expression where I create a variable called `value` that is set equal to my drop-down list. From looking at the examples I have found on the internet I understand the logic of how to set up the statement, I am just not understanding how to allocate the items in my drop-down box to the `value` variable for the statement. This would be a huge help because also in the `Select Case` statement there are other drop-down lists that should hold different constant values for every item based on the user selection of the first drop-down box

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub CalculateButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CalculateButton.Click
        Dim value As String = AirlineDropDown.SelectedValue
        Dim BagValue As String = NumBagsDropDown.SelectedValue
        Dim OvWBagValue As String = OverweightDropdown.SelectedValue
        Dim Total, Bagtotal, OvWBagTotal, DamagePro As Double
        DamagePro = 12.0

        Select Case value
            Case Airtran
                ' set Constant values to Bagvalues and OvWBagValues based on user selection  
        End Select

        Total = Bagtotal + OvWBagTotal + DamagePro
        TotalTextbox.Text = FormatNumber(Total, 2)
    End Sub

    Protected Sub ClearButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ClearButton.Click
        TotalTextbox.Text = ""
    End Sub 
End Class
```

[Image of my webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MOdY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track, you just need to compare value to strings. Using the word Airtran on its own would never return true unless it was part of an Airline enum or something. The cost of Airtran's bag fee also needs to be multiplied by the number of bags the user selects, so I've added that to the example below (BagValue must also be converted to an integer to perform multiplication). Lastly, when comparing strings, I tend to like making my string comparisons case-insensitive, so I would handle the select-case like this:

```
'Converting the number of bags into an integer
Dim BagValue As Integer = CInt(NumBagsDropDown.SelectedValue)
Dim OvWBagValue As Integer = CInt(OverweightDropdown.SelectedValue)

Select Case True
    Case value.ToUpper.Equals("AIRTRAN")
        Bagtotal = 15 * BagValue          '15, or whatever airtran's bag fee is
        OvWBagTotal = 20 * OvWBagValue    'also made this number up
    'etc
End Select
```

Also, since DamagePro is a checkbox, you would only want to add the 12 if it is checked, currently your code will add it regardless of its checked state. That would look something like:

```
Total = Bagtotal + OvWBagTotal
If DamageProChkBox.Checked Then Total += DamagePro
TotalTextbox.Text = FormatNumber(Total, 2)
```

---

Comment Edit: You don't need a select-case statement for the number of bags, you should be able to retrieve those from the dropdownlist. For example, {Text="1 Overweight Bag", Value="1"}, {Text="2 Overweight Bags", Value="2"}. Since both normal bags and overweight have their own separate dropdownlists, you are able to get counts from each of them for each type of bag. Dropdownlists kind of already work like pre-built select-case statements, because depending on the user's selection they will provide you with different values when you retrieve their "SelectedValue", so there is no need to use further select-case statements to get their retrieved value. The select-case would be used primarily, in your case, for the total calculation; meaning that it allows you to have different dollar values for different airlines' bag fees.

Comment: Wow Thank you so much!!! So can I Do the same thing BagValue and the OvWbagvalue that you did with Value.ToUpper.Equals since they're also strings in their own drop-down list and if so There are only three items(1,2, or 3 bags) on both of the list, so can i just kind of do a nested statement for the three options?

Comment: Added response to the post, it was too long to fit as a comment

Answer (score 0):

Please use string here

```
Select Case value
  Case value
            ' set Constant values to Bagvalues and OvWBagValues based on user selection  
End Select
```